# Hibernate 5, Oracle12c Identity column - sequence not found

Tags: java, identity, oracle12c, hibernate-5.x

I am facing the following error when trying to insert a Person record to the DB.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02201: sequence not allowed here
```

I am wokring with Hibernate 5.2.12.Final, Oracle 12 c database and making use of Identity column in the DB for 'id'.

```
select 1 from dual
```

Works. So I am sure the DB connection is a success.

Below is the config:

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
id NUMBER(18) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT pk_person PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

HibernateUtil

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {


        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure(new File("path-to-hibernate.cfg.xml"))
                .build();

        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Person.class)
                .addAnnotatedClassName("com.example.entity.Person")
                .getMetadataBuilder()
                .applyImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.INSTANCE)
                .build();

        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder()
                .build();


    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    if (registry != null) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
}
}
```

Person entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

public Person(){}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Person(final String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
}
```

main ():

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(new Person("code")); // Error here

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead `GenerationType.IDENTITY`  try to use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` and it should work, let me know if it doesn't because nothing looks wrong in your code except that.

Comment: With that change, I get the following in the log:
`Hibernate: select system.hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual`
`Hibernate: insert into system.Person (name, id) values (?, ?)`
But the error remains. Sequence not allowed here.
Also, I would want to use the IDENTITY sequence associated with 'id' and not hibernate_sequence

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide me sample code in zip file

Comment: Creating the same under a non-system user seemed to solve the issue. No code changes were done.